# SQL-Group same columns data except one field where if it is Yes return null

Tags: sql, oracle

Example:

[image: Example]

I want to write an oracle query where I can check if someone in the same department have the same skills. So, department = 1, sql = 'Y', jquery = 'Y'. But, at least 1 person must be active = 'Y'. I want to write a query that returns 1 (for true) because at least 1 person (John) has all the skills and is active despite Jame's active column is null.

Expected Result: 1

```
SELECT 1 FROM test_table WHERE department = 1 AND sql = 'Y' AND Jquery = 'Y'
```

Comment: Edit the question add expected result too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the result you want with a self-join of the table, where you look for two different people who have the same skill set, and check that one of the people is active:

```
SELECT Department
FROM skills s1
JOIN skills s2 ON s2.Name < s1.Name AND s2.SQL = s1.SQL AND s2.JQuery = s1.JQuery
WHERE s1.Active = 'Y' OR s2.Active = 'Y'
```

You can also use an `EXISTS` clause the same way:

```
SELECT s1.Department
FROM skills s1
WHERE s1.Active = 'Y'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM skills s2
              WHERE s2.Name != s1.Name AND s2.SQL = s1.SQL AND s2.JQUery = s1.JQuery)
```

In both cases the output for your sample data is:

```
DEPARTMENT
1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3a2c3f4d35ac2a2af2eeaa03f94f7c78)

Comment: Working! Thank you!